# SDK in C++ need to call those function in python

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, sdk

There is an sdk(Microsoft Visual Studio C++) for motherboard that can be very useful to me but it's written in C++ and I know python.
This sdk has has alot of predefine function in it and return some value according to function called.
All I need to know is how cam I make those function call from a sdk that is written in C++ in python all I'm interested is in the return value I don't have to make any changes in the sdk

```
#pragma once

typedef int (*LPMLAPI_Initialize)();
typedef int (*LPMLAPI_GetDeviceInfo)(SAFEARRAY** pDevType, SAFEARRAY** pLedCount);
typedef int (*LPMLAPI_GetDeviceName)(BSTR type, SAFEARRAY** pDevName);
typedef int (*LPMLAPI_GetDeviceNameEx)(BSTR type, DWORD index, BSTR* pDevName);
typedef int (*LPMLAPI_GetErrorMessage)(int ErrorCode, BSTR* pDesc);
typedef int (*LPMLAPI_GetLedName)(BSTR type, SAFEARRAY** pLedName);
```

These are the function(there are many more) in the 'Application_SDK.h' file which is a header

I want some way to able to call this function in python and get the output

```
int MLAPI_Initialize()
Description: This function initializes the APIs. This must be called before calling other MLAPI_ functions.
```

the above function can return the following

```
Return values:
    MLAPI_OK Initialized.
    MLAPI_NO_IMPLEMENTED MSI application not found or current version is not supported.
    MLAPI_INITIAL_TIMEOUT MLAPI_Initialize timeout
```

.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling C/C++ from Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145270/calling-c-c-from-python)

Comment: it kind of gives some sort of direction I should be looking into but not really